# How can I correctly process this file containing tab separated values in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am fairly new to Perl and know next to nothing about Perl's 'proper' syntax.

I have a text file that I use everyday with a listing of names, and other info for our users. This file changes daily and sometimes has two rows in it(tab delimited), and other times has 100+ rows in it.

The file also varies between 6-9 columns of data in a row. I have put together a Perl script that uses the split function on tabs, but the issue I am running into is that if I take row *a*, which has 5 columns in it and then add a second row *b* that has 6 columns in it that are all populated with data.

I cannot figure out how to get Perl to see that row a only has 5 columns of data and to continue parsing the text file from that point forward. It continues, but the output wraps lines strangely. How can I get around this issue? I hope that made sense.

Comment: Post some code and sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to post some code and possibly some sample data, but here's a code that is parsing rows of different lengths without issue.

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

while (<STDIN>)
{
    chomp;
    my @info = split("\t");
    print join(";", @info), "\n";
}

exit;
```

**Test File:**

```
  jsmith  101     777-222-5555    Office 1        Building 1      Manager 
  aposse  104     777-222-5556    Office 2        Building 2      Stock Clerk 
  jbraza  105     777-222-5557    Office 3 
  mcuzui  102     777-222-5557    Office 3        Building 3      Cashier 
  ghines  107     777-222-5557    Office 3
```

**Output:**

```
%> test.pl < file.txt
jsmith;101;777-222-5555;Office 1;Building 1;Manager
aposse;104;777-222-5556;Office 2;Building 2;Stock Clerk
jbraza;105;777-222-5557;Office 3
mcuzui;102;777-222-5557;Office 3;Building 3;Cashier
ghines;107;777-222-5557;Office 3
```

Comment: I realized the error of my way, I had my split syntax incorrect. Thank you, I really appreciate the help from everyone on here. Have a good afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

You should post some sample data and code and explain desired behavior in terms of what the code currently does and what you want it to do. [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) will give you as many fields as there are in the input.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $row =~ /\S/;
    chomp $row;
    my @cells = split /\t/, $row;
    print "< @cells >\n";
}

__DATA__
1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, as stated above, I had my syntax incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

[Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module can be used for parsing tab-separated-values as well. In reality, [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) could parse values delimited by any character.

Relevant excerpt from its POD:

> The module accepts either strings or
>   files as input and can utilize any
>   user-specified characters as
>   delimiters, separators, and escapes so
>   it is perhaps better called ASV
>   (anything separated values) rather
>   than just CSV.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { 'sep_char' => "\t" } );

open my $fh, '<', 'data.tsv' or die "Unable to open: $!";

my @rows;
while ( my $row_ref = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    push @rows, $row_ref;
}

$csv->sep_char('|');
for my $row_ref (@rows) {
    $csv->combine(@$row_ref);
    print $csv->string(), "\n";
}
```